# Does my server need a registered domain name if it is only accessed from mobile application?

Tags: android

I want to develop an app for android and am a newbie to pretty much anything server related.  I want my app to be able to perform simple get and post requests to my server.  I don't intend on hosting a website on it and it will only be accessed by the app.  Do I still need to get a registered domain name or can I directly access the ip address of my server?  Obviously it would have to be able to be accessed by things other than the local network the server is on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with doing it with the IP address is: "What if the IP changes?". With a domain you can just update the DNS records and the app will work as expected, but if you hardcode the IP you're going to have to have everybody update it.

Look into services like [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) which will provide a free subdomain and manage DNS for you.

Comment: I was just about to suggest this when I saw the answers come in.  Biggest concern is having the IP change.  DynDNS is great for managing this!

Comment: Biggest concern or only concern? I see no other disadvantages. And if you are sure that the IP won't change in the near future, why not use the resolved IP ...

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by IP address instead of using a servername, but often a static IP will cost more than $8 per year, which is about what domain names cost.

If it's not about cost, and you're more concerned with how to set up a domain name with a machine on your local network - You can get free [dynamic DNS service](http://www.dyndns.com/) with pretty minimal setup.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access via IP. You just need to remember that, though highly unlikely, your IP could change without warning and your app would need to be updated.  I purchased a domain name and use dynamic dns (dyndns.org) to host my zone file.

They provide you with ways to ensure that the IP is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Even in your situation, a domain name is a good idea. It makes things look more official to reviewers and insulates you in case your server's IP address changes (rather than having to re-build your re-distribute your app).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if your server is hosted on a shared IP with other servers using what are called host headers.

If you can open a browser and put http://10.10.10.10 (replace ip with your server's ip and assuming your server is answering on port 80, stock http port), and get your server to respond, then no you don't need a domain.

As mentioned above, its a bad idea though.  IPs do change and having a DNS pointing to a domain is the only way to deal with it without having to force all your mobile users to update the app in the event of a change.